# How to effectively iterate by many foreignkey objects with Django ORM?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

Let's say that I have `model` like:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):

  ...
  seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, related_name="user", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  ...
```

And I trying to get `seller` email address using this code:

```py
from app.models import User
from django_print_sql import print_sql

with print_sql(count_only=False):
  users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, seller_id__isnull=False).select_related().only('seller__email')
  for u in users.iterator():
    email = u.seller.email
    send_email(email)
```

In this case I can see SQL queries like:

```sql
SELECT `user`.`id`,
       `user`.`seller_id`
FROM `user`
WHERE (`user`.`is_active`
       AND `user`.`seller_id` IS NOT NULL)

...

SELECT `seller`.`id`,
       ...
       `seller`.`email`,
       ...
FROM `seller`
WHERE `seller`.`id` = 1

...
```

The problem is Django ORM accessing DB at every iteration (`Select seller... where seller.id = ...`). So that will be too many queries (== DB connections) if we have many sellers.

In other way it is possible to replace `only` with `values`:

```py
from app.models import User
from django_print_sql import print_sql

with print_sql(count_only=False):
  users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, seller_id__isnull=False).select_related().values('seller__email')
  for u in users.iterator():
    email = u['seller__email']
    send_email(email)
```

And I can see SQL query like:

```sql
SELECT `seller`.`email`
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `seller` ON (`user`.`seller_id` = `seller`.`id`)
WHERE (`user`.`is_active`
       AND `user`.`seller_id` IS NOT NULL)
```

It is little bit better and we able to get emails by single DB query, but `iterator` is useless here because we load all emails once inside `dict` object and whole data exists inside memory.

**The question is**
Is it possible to iterate by data chunks (Let say by 500 emails/single query) without create manual sub-loops limiting `User.objects.filter` query count? Or in other words, what is most effective iterator in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your case You give no parameters for `select_related`, I suggest You to put `seller` field to `select_related` like this:

```py
from app.models import User
from django_print_sql import print_sql

with print_sql(count_only=False):
  users = User.objects.select_related('seller').filter(is_active=True, seller_id__isnull=False).only('seller__email')
  for u in users.iterator():
    email = u.seller.email
    send_email(email)
```

putting `select_related` before `objects` manager. By doing this django retreives seller model records as a field for every iterated user and will not hit the database in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `select_related` is working for this case:

```py
from app.models import User
from django_print_sql import print_sql

with print_sql(count_only=False):
  users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, seller_id__isnull=False).select_related('seller').only('seller__email').exclude(seller__email__exact='')
  for u in users.iterator():
    send_email(u.seller.email)
```

```sql
SELECT `user`.`id`,
       `user`.`owner_id`,
       `seller`.`id`,
       `seller`.`email`
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `seller` ON (`user`.`seller_id` = `seller`.`id`)
WHERE (`user`.`is_active`
       AND `user`.`seller_id` IS NOT NULL
       AND NOT (`seller`.`email` =
                AND `seller`.`email` IS NOT NULL))
```